# How to modify the Socialist Millionaire Protocol to be symmetric.

Tags: cryptanalysis, diffie-hellman, implementation, key-exchange, zero-knowledge-proofs

In the Socialist Millionaire Protocol, the roles of Alice and Bob are *almost* symmetric. By this I mean they do *almost* the same thing, until the very last step.

In the final step, both parties check a value like $R_{ab} == P_{alice} / P_{bob}$. So the parties have to agree who's the numerator (alice), and who's the denominator (bob) ([reference](https://otr.cypherpunks.ca/Protocol-v2-3.1.0.html)).

But I noticed I can avoid this asymmetry by just checking for both $P_{alice} / P_{bob} $ and $P_{both} / P_{alice}$. Or more explicitly, with the roles removed.

$$
(R_{ab} == P_{self} / P_{other}) \text{  or  } (R_{ab} == P_{other} / P_{self})
$$

My question is: is this safe? Is there some way an attacker could use this extra check to interfere with the final result?

If it is the case that both parties *do* have the same secret value, this should always work. But if the parties *don't* have the same value, could the adversary make my extra check return true somehow?

Here is my code for reference:
https://github.com/cowlicks/socialist-millionaire-go/blob/master/smp.go#L129-L138

Comment: If this is a dangerous thing to do, then it seems like it would make [this implementation](https://github.com/python-otr/pure-python-otr/blob/master/src/potr/crypt.py#L498) vulnerable. Because an adversary could just lie about the `proto.SMP2TLV` or`proto.SMP3TLV` flag.